# Matlab engine and disp() function

Tags: matlab, matlab-engine

I have a script that take some time to execute. I launch it in a C++ function, using Matlab Engine.
To monitor the execution of the script, I wanted to add some `disp('still alive')` into it. However, it does not work, nothing is displayed into the matlab command window opened by engOpen (yes, I am sure the script is running, since I get output files at the execution end).

Any idea how I could get it to work ?

Beside, is it possible to get such heartbeats **at script runtime**, into the Windows command using engOutputBuffer ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `engOutputBuffer`, `engEvalString` and `printf` to get output to console (to Windows command window, not MATLAB command window).

If you want to monitor progress of your script, you can open m-script file in your C code and execute it command-by-command with `engEvalString`. After each executed command `printf` buffer contents to console window. The main problem in this approach is how to isolate (parse) commands in opened m-script file, but if you expect certain kind of scripts this can be done.

The other way you can achieve monitoring of messages is to open a thread after `engOutputBuffer` which will check content of the buffer and execute `printf` in parallel to execution of the m-script started in a main thread.

Check example at [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/162046) (near bottom of the page) on how to output MATLAB messages to console (Windows command).

Comment: Duh. In my first question, I said "matlab command". Concerning my second question, I know how to do it, what I asked is : is it possible to output stuff into windows command AT SCRIPT RUNTIME.

Comment: Open .m script in your c code and execute line by line with engEvalString. I mentioned console output in my answer,  not matlab command window.

Comment: Executing a script line by line is an idea, though too much dependent on the underlying script. Eventually, I'd like to read ANY script and monitor its execution. Edit your answer with your last comment pls.